# Android Image Color Filter Application

Tags: android, photoshop

I want to make a color effect application for android.
How to apply a color effect to image by code on Android Studio ? Example Images;
[image]

[image]

I have no idea about how to implement color effects to image by code. For example if I want to implement this effects from Photoshop, what can I do ?
[image]

Final result that I expect;
[image]

Comment: You'd have to parse the original photo pixel by pixel changing each pixels value according to your "filter", which could for instance be increasing the r (red) value of the pixel in order to highlight the redness of the image. On how to implement more complex filters like blur, sharpen or smudge you can find plenty of information online.

Answer (score -1):

create a view on top of the image and set the background color to the desired one and reduce increase the transparency

```
<FrameLayout
      android:height="wrap_content"
      android:width="wrap_content">
      <ImageView
          android:height="yourheight"
          android:width="yourwidth"
          android:src="@drawable/yourimage" />
      <View
          android:height="match_parent"
          android:width="match_parent"
          android:background="yourcolorinAGBRformat">
</FrameLayout>
```

---

Thank You !